# How to not repeat myself in Gitlab CI/CD with multiple stages

Tags: angular, firebase, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm using gitlab CI/CD to deploy my angular app on firebase. 
I have 2 stage: `build` and `deploy`.

```
image: node:11.2.0

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm i
    - npm i -g @angular/cli@7.3.1
    - ng build --prod
  only:
    - master
    - dev
    - merge_requests

deploy_prod:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - npm i
    - npm i -g @angular/cli@7.3.1
    - ng build --prod
    - npm i -g firebase-tools
    - firebase use --token "$FIREBASE_TOKEN" project-name
    - firebase deploy --token "$FIREBASE_TOKEN" --non-interactive
  environment:
    name: prod
  only:
    - master
```

As you can see I have too repeat in the deploy stage:

```
- npm i
- npm i -g @angular/cli@7.3.1
- ng build --prod
```

Is there a way to use what has been done to make the CI/CD faster?

What is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

There can be multiple approaches to it. You can move them to an external script and call that or the best way forward is to use [anchors](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#anchors). Example:

```
.job_template: &job_definition  # Hidden key that defines an anchor named 'job_definition'
  image: ruby:2.1
  services:
    - postgres
    - redis

test1:
  <<: *job_definition           # Merge the contents of the 'job_definition' alias
  script:
    - test1 project

test2:
  <<: *job_definition           # Merge the contents of the 'job_definition' alias
  script:
    - test2 project
```

Comment: Thanks it seems to work but the `ng build --prod` generated a dist folder in the build stage, which is normal. But for the deploy stage the script do not see this folder. so I think the 2 stages don't share the same volume. How can I solve that without re-building everything?

Comment: @Kevin I suggest searching or posting a separate question since your original question was to do with writing the yaml, not persisting files if you're still having issues, but I recommend reading over this section on cache/artifacts: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#cache-vs-artifacts

Comment: Actually my question was about that at the beginning. This is why I was asking how to make the CI faster. Maybe I did not explain well myself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Arty-chan the solution is with Artifacts: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#cache-vs-artifacts

```
image: node:11.2.0

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

.job_template: &job_definition
  script:
    - npm i
    - npm i -g @angular/cli@7.3.1
    - ng build --prod

build:
  stage: build
  <<: *job_definition
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/
  only:
    - master
    - dev
    - merge_requests

deploy_prod:
  stage: deploy
  <<: *job_definition
  script:
    - npm i -g firebase-tools
    - firebase use --token "$FIREBASE_TOKEN" project-name
    - firebase deploy --token "$FIREBASE_TOKEN" --non-interactive
  environment:
    name: prod
  only:
    - master
```